# Bubble Sort algorithm not working properly (javascript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bubble-sort

Ok, so i have this weird problem with my bubble sort algorithm. It shifts to the right like it should for a little while, but it suddenly stops in the middle and shifting smaller numbers to the left instead of keep going to the right. This is btw done in P5.js, but i'm not sure if that's the issue.

I'm really confused since this is such a easy algoritm and I got it working in python.

Code:

```
let arr3 = [90, 10, 40, 70, 5, 30, 20, 60, 80, 50];


function setup(){
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(51);
  frameRate(1);
}

function draw(){
  background(51);
  bubbleSort(arr3);   //Initiating Bubble Sort
}

function bubbleSort(a){       //Bubble Sort algorithm
  let run = true;
  while(run){
    run = false;
    for(let i=0; i<a.length-1; i++){
      if(a[i] > a[i+1]){
        let temp = a[i+1];   //Swapping 
        a[i+1] = a[i];
        a[i] = temp;
        run = true;
        console.log(a);      //Printing current array
        return a;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[10, 90, 40, 70, 5, 30, 20, 60, 80, 50]
[10, 40, 90, 70, 5, 30, 20, 60, 80, 50]
[10, 40, 70, 90, 5, 30, 20, 60, 80, 50]
[10, 40, 70, 5, 90, 30, 20, 60, 80, 50] //The 90 should keep going but
[10, 40, 5, 70, 90, 30, 20, 60, 80, 50] //it stops and 5 keep swapping
[10, 5, 40, 70, 90, 30, 20, 60, 80, 50] //with bigger numbers..
[5, 10, 40, 70, 90, 30, 20, 60, 80, 50]
[5, 10, 40, 70, 30, 90, 20, 60, 80, 50]
[5, 10, 40, 30, 70, 90, 20, 60, 80, 50]
[5, 10, 30, 40, 70, 90, 20, 60, 80, 50]
[5, 10, 30, 40, 70, 20, 90, 60, 80, 50]
[5, 10, 30, 40, 20, 70, 90, 60, 80, 50]
[5, 10, 30, 20, 40, 70, 90, 60, 80, 50]
[5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 70, 90, 60, 80, 50]
[5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 70, 60, 90, 80, 50]
[5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70, 90, 80, 50]
[5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90, 50]
[5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70, 80, 50, 90]
[5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70, 50, 80, 90]
[5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 50, 70, 80, 90]
[5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```

Comment: I don't see any `9`s in there...

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with the flow of this program either. The behavior is exactly as it should be for bubblesort.

Comment: Here's [a correct example implementation of bubble sort](https://github.com/patrickroberts/sort-viz/blob/master/lib/comparative/bubble.js) using a generator function. Just ignore the `yield *` operators and try to follow the basic logic. Looking at your `bubbleSort()` function, it does not appear to match the basic logic.

Comment: The 90 won’t “keep going” to the right because you return after making the first swap.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I meant 90

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, that's the same thing I've done just wrote in a different way. Also have tried that before with the same result.

Comment: The first problem is that you have a `return` in the middle of your algorithm. What you have there is not a bubble sort. A typical bubble sort would have two loops, not one.

Comment: _"but that don't explain why it shifting to the right at the beginning and suddenly stops. Or em I missing something here?"_ What you are currently doing equates to "Go through the array there are two elements that need to be swapped. Then swap them and start from the beginning of the array." The reason the 90 stops moving is that as once the 5 moves to the left of the 90, the process above begins swapping the 5 further to the left and then starting over from the beginning. It doesn't reach the 90 until everything to the left of the 90 has been sorted.

Comment: @James, you are right. When I remove the return a; the algorithm works. But the idea is to use the number returned so i can plot the result and watch how the algorithm move. How can I do that without the return? If i put the return after the for-loop the plot is way to fast..

Comment: You could call a function that does your plotting from within the for loop.

Comment: @James, ok! I tried to draw a rectangle with no stroke, a green fill  and rect(10 + (i*10), 399, 9, a[i+1]);  I put all this in the bubbleSort function in the if-state, but this do not work either.. I also tried to do frameRate(1); to see if something happens to fast, but it seems like it won't work. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with P5.js, but I think the issue is just where you placed your return statement. You'll want to have your final return outside of your while loop like this:

```
function bubbleSort(a){       //Bubble Sort algorithm
  let run = true;
  while(run){
    run = false;
    for(let i=0; i<a.length-1; i++){
      if(a[i] > a[i+1]){
        let temp = a[i+1];   //Swapping 
        a[i+1] = a[i];
        a[i] = temp;
        run = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two loop and at least your second loop should two times. Than it works correctly

```html
function bubbleSort(arr) {
    var i, j;
    var len = arr.length;
    var isSwapped = false;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        isSwapped = false;
        
        for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                var temp = arr[j]
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
                isSwapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isSwapped) {
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(arr)
}
   
var arr = [8,20,-2,-4, 11, -1];
bubbleSort(arr);
```